Formalizing that formula is a tautology
After successully formalizing the formal system with axioms from Mendelsons book I am slowly moving towards proving 2 theorems:

Every theorem of L is a tautology.
Every tautology is a theorem of L.

Here is the formalism for a formula.
To prove them we need to build an interpreter for a formula and define a tautology. We can create a mapping between atoms and booleans. And given a formula we need a map between every atom (symbol) of the formula and it's boolean value. So I created the following interpreter:
fixpoint eval (f : formula) (values : atom -> bool) : bool :=
    match f with
    | f_atom a => values a
    | f_not f' => negb (eval f')
    | f_impl f1 f2 =>
        match (eval f1) with
        | false => true
        | true => eval f2
        end
    end.

I am not sure, how can we prove that values contain a value for every symbol in formula.
How to define that formula f is a tautology?
I tried to explain:
Definition tautology (f : formula) : Prop :=
    If forall possible values of the variables in f, 
    (eval f value[i]) returns true, then formula f is a tautology.

Attempt to evaluate a formula
Fixpoint eval (value : atom -> bool) (f : formula) : bool :=
  match f with
  | f_atom a => value a
  | f_not f => negb (eval value f)
  | f_imp f1 f2 => implb (eval value f1) (eval value f2)
end.

Definition tautology (f : formula) : Prop :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v f).

Definition test_formula (a b : atom) := f_imp (f_atom a) (f_atom b).

(* Doesn't work *)
Definition iterpretation (var : atom) : bool :=
  match var with
  | a => true
  | b => false
  end.

Eval eval interpretation test_formula;


You should check your code in Rocq (it just got renamed and has a new web site at https://rocq-prover.org) before posting it here: firpoint, negb eval f'?

You wrote most of the answer yourself, you would just have to typing it into Rocq and clean it up. Your use of module seems strange, I changed that to a Section (note how atom is introduced using Context so that after the section is closed, it becomes an implicit parameter.)
Section Formula.
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Context {atom : Set}.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Scope formula_scope.
Open Scope formula_scope.
Declare Custom Entry formula_view.

(* Заполняем нотации с учетом приоритета *)
Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom formula_view at level 1, in custom formula_view at level 1).

(*
Импликация слабее конъюнкции и дизъюнкции, но она нужна для их определений
поэтому нотацию для неё вводим раньше.
 *)
Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 4).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 5, at level 0).

Check fun p q => f_imp (f_imp (f_not (f_atom q)) (f_not (f_atom p))) (f_imp (f_atom p) (f_atom q)).
Definition conjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~(A -> ~B)$.
Notation "A /\ B" := (conjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 2, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition disjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~A -> B$.
Notation "A \/ B" := (disjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 3, in custom formula_view at level 3, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition equivalence (A B: formula) : formula := $(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)$.
Notation "A <-> B" := (equivalence A B) (B custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 5, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 77) : formula_scope.

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) (A : formula) := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 78, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 79) : formula_scope.

Fixpoint eval (value : atom -> bool) (f : formula) : bool :=
  match f with
  | f_atom a => value a
  | f_not f => negb (eval value f)
  | f_imp f1 f2 => implb (eval value f1) (eval value f2)
end.

Definition tautology (f : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v f).
End Formula.

(* Example on how to write an actual formula and evaluate it. *)

(* A type with three atoms. *)
Inductive atom3 : Set :=
  | x1 : atom3
  | x2 : atom3
  | x3 : atom3.

(* A valuation. *)
Definition val3 (x : atom3) : bool :=
  match x with
  | x1 => false
  | x2 => true
  | x3 => false
  end.

(* Evaluate ¬ (x₁ ⇒ x₂) at v. *)
Eval compute in eval val3 (f_not (f_imp (f_atom x1) (f_atom x2))).

The example is a bit clumsy because we had to define a silly type with three atoms, but it serves its purpose. If you actually had to evaluate lots of concrete formulas, you could organize a more convenient version of atom that wouldn't require you to define an inductive type like atom3. From what I understand, you're going to mostly prove meta-theorems, which is what the code is good for.

"The use of Module in your code seems like a complication. Why do you want a module?" - I thought it would be better to move the formula definition into a separate file and have 2 files: one for syntactic theory and one --- on semantic (eval). This is the second file: https://gist.github.com/usr345/f412755a514434aaeb2ef4156c4a9ed1. Is there a better solution?

I updated the answer. Could you explain, how to build iterpretation function for a, b?

That's not what module does. If you move a piece of code into a separate file, then you don't put an additional Module in that file.

How to use notation $A -> B$ after closing the section? It gives an error: "Error: Syntax Error: Lexer: Undefined token"

Theorem implies_tautology A B : (logically_implies A B) <-> (tautology $A -> B$).

Can you give an example with Module and without Section? I will need to import it and use notations, and I won't able to get them from section. The Context is totally implicit, and I don't understand, how it works.

Probably, it's better at first to write everything explicitly.
